# Как можно отловить local notification когда приложение находится в background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, уведомления

Какие есть варианты, при срабатывании local notification во время нахождения приложения в background словить его и вызвать нужный метод. Без вмешательства пользователя (нажатия на саму alert). Например уведомление срабатывает в час ночи каждый день, и в этот момент вызывается функция которая подтягивает погодные данные с сервера. 
Позволяет ли User Notification framework такое сделать? Или есть какие то другие варианты?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, такой возможности нет. iOS готова время от времени вызывать функции обновления у вашего приложения, но она не гарантирует точную частоту и время этих вызовов (это остается на ее усмотрение). Кроме того, iOS не разрешает долгое время работать никаким фоновым программам кроме музыки и геопозиционирования.

Answer (score 1):

Для вашей задачи подойдут Background Update Notification, они подобны "обычным" нотификациям, за тем исключением что когда приходят нет ни звука ни алерта, поэтому их ещё называют silent notifications, так же они содержат в себе флаг content-available = 1, который обозначает, что есть payload, к примеру, это может быть ссылка на удаленный ресурс к которому надо обратится, доступ к пэйлоаду вы можете получить в методе didReceiveRemoteNotification. Основная соль этих нотификаций, в том что когда приложение было в бэкграунде и система его "усыпила", систем же пробуждает приложение и вы получаете некоторый лимит времени а так же пэйлоад в метод didReceiveRemoteNotification. Эпл просить отправлять нотификации не чаще чем 2-3 штуки в час, для вас этого будет вполне достаточно

Answer (score 0):

Для этого не обязательно так извращаться. Для актуальных данных погоды вы можете их начать асинхронно подгружать их в

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

и хранить их в каком нить singletone.
И да у вас приложение в background живет не более 10 мин